# Android browser - localhost communication (phone tiny webserver)

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, android-browser

Would it be possible to start on the Android phone background running service which will listen on a certain port for incoming local http connections and communicate with the the built-in web browser (I am not talking about the web view), Opera or Dolphin browser by capturing all such localhost calls - `http://localhost:8081/serviceCall`?

The goal is to make a tiny webserver running on Android phone, which can deliver the web browser some information, the browser does not have access to. But I am not sure if there are not some security restrictions, etc.

BR
Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it technically possible? Sure.

Is it wise? Only if you are a security expert or have a large legal defense fund. You will not be just sending data to "the built-in web browser", but to any application that chooses to make HTTP requests.

Comment: First - thanks for comment! What do you mean by 'any application'? There will be my service running - are you referring to the possibility that someone else will install a his own service and capture my requests?

Comment: The reason I need that is only to check in JavaScript that my Android application is installed and if not start it. So far we come to the conclusion that there is no reliable way how to determine in browser some application is/is not installed. Please note that tablets we are using have not access to the Internet (i.e. Google Play), they are used only in the local network.

Comment: @STeN: "What do you mean by 'any application'?" -- I mean any application installed on the device that has the `INTERNET` permission. Plus, if you screw up and have your `ServerSocket` not be tied to `localhost`, add in any program on any other machine that can reach the IP address of the device. "are you referring to the possibility that someone else will install a his own service and capture my requests?" -- no, I am referring to the possibility that someone writes an app to make HTTP requests of your server.

Comment: @STeN: "So far we come to the conclusion that there is no reliable way how to determine in browser some application is/is not installed." -- correct. The user of the device will need to be able to start and stop the server. "Please note that tablets we are using have not access to the Internet (i.e. Google Play), they are used only in the local network." -- that helps a bit, but not completely.